# Chart with flexible data series

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a chart with flexible upper and lower range. I already plotted my chart with the complete data series. When I click on the chart and select the graph, selected data is like this:

```
DATASERIES(Sheets1!$C$1,Sheets1!$A$2:$A$2800,Sheets1!$C$2:$C$2800,2)
```

Now I am going to give this chart my inputs as the initial and end of the chart. For example to insert two numbers in different cells like Lower band=100 & upper band=2500, and have Excel to plot the chart in the specified range.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you cannot link your maximum and minimum bounds to cell values. You'd need to use VBA for that.

Comment: @JustynaMK no, it should be possible

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I still couldn't find non-VBA solution on Google (I thought that maybe one of the newest releases of Excel offers this functionality). For years we needed to use VBA to link chat's max and min bounds to cell values. If you find any other alternative then I'm happy to learn about it, otherwise try the VBA solution, like: https://exceloffthegrid.com/chart-axis-min-mix/